# How do you force the default mail app to resync it's folder list with exchange?

Tags: email, exchange, stock-email-app

I've got a Kyocera Duraforce that appears to have it's folder list out of sync with our exchange server. A large number of folders were created and shortly afterwards deleted and the deleted folders weren't ever deleted off of the device, as a result looking at the all-folders list to find a specific folder is tedious at best. How can I force the phone to resync it's folder list with the exchange server? I'm using the default mail app.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, the only solution that I was able to find was to delete the account from the phone and recreate it. Also, after testing the phone had a number of other issues related to folders on that account so it appears as if the account had gotten corrupted in some fashion.